# Resources not available in Azure portal after successful bicep deployment

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I am very new to Bicep. I have created a test bicep solution in VSCode as below:

1. main.bicep

   ```
    param prefix string
    param environment string
    param deploymentLocation string
    @allowed(['prod','non-prod'])
    param environmentType string

    var storageAccountSkuName = (environmentType == 'prod') ? 'Standard_GRS' : 'Standard_LRS'

    targetScope = 'subscription'

    resource resourceGroup 'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2023-07-01' = {
      name: '${prefix}-${environment}-rg'
      location: deploymentLocation
    }

    module storageAccount 'storage.bicep' = {
      scope: resourceGroup
      name: 'storageModule'
      params: {
        storageAccountName: '${prefix}${environment}sa'
        storageAccountLocation: deploymentLocation
        storageAccountSkuName: storageAccountSkuName
     }
   }
   ```
2. storage.bicep

   ```
   param storageAccountName string
   param storageAccountLocation string //= resourceGroup().location
   param storageAccountSkuName string

   resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-01-01' = {
     name: storageAccountName
     location: storageAccountLocation
     sku: {
       name: storageAccountSkuName
     }
     kind: 'Storage'
   }
   ```

In the main.bicep, when I only had 'resource resourceGroup' code, the deployment went well and I could see the resource group in Azure portal. Once done, I deleted the resourceGroup manually from the Azure portal.

Now, after adding 'module storageAccount' code to the main.bicep file, I am trying to deploy main.bicep using below CLI command:

```
az deployment sub create --name AbcTest-sub --location eastus --template-file main.bicep
```

I get below output:

```html
A new Bicep release is available: v0.25.53. Upgrade now by running "az bicep upgrade".
Please provide string value for 'prefix' (? for help): abc
Please provide string value for 'environment' (? for help): dev
Please provide string value for 'deploymentLocation' (? for help): eastus
Please provide string value for 'environmentType' (? for help): 
 [1] prod
 [2] non-prod
Please enter a choice [Default choice(1)]: 2
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/21fc5d5d-8ee6-4850-8b7e-2fdcf71d834b/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/AbcTest-sub",
  "location": "eastus",
  "name": "AbcTest-sub",
  "properties": {
    "correlationId": "b0612345-c75b-4683-86e1-e6fee6a2c503",
    "debugSetting": null,
    "dependencies": [
      {
        "dependsOn": [
          {
            "id": "/subscriptions/21fc5d5d-8ee6-4850-8b7e-2fdcf71d834b/resourceGroups/abc-dev-rg",
            "resourceName": "abc-dev-rg",
            "resourceType": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups"
          }
        ],
        "id": "/subscriptions/21fc5d5d-8ee6-4850-8b7e-2fdcf71d834b/resourceGroups/abc-dev-rg/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/storageModule",
        "resourceGroup": "abc-dev-rg",
        "resourceName": "storageModule",
        "resourceType": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments"
      }
    ],
    "duration": "PT35.0652943S",
    "error": null,
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "onErrorDeployment": null,
    "outputResources": [
      {
        "id": "/subscriptions/21fc5d5d-8ee6-4850-8b7e-2fdcf71d834b/resourceGroups/abc-dev-rg"
      },
      {
        "id": "/subscriptions/21fc5d5d-8ee6-4850-8b7e-2fdcf71d834b/resourceGroups/abc-dev-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/abcdevsa",
        "resourceGroup": "abc-dev-rg"
      }
    ],
    "outputs": null,
    "parameters": {
      "deploymentLocation": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "eastus"
      },
      "environment": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "dev"
      },
      "environmentType": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "non-prod"
      },
      "prefix": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "abc"
      }
    },
    "parametersLink": null,
    "providers": [
      {
        "id": null,
        "namespace": "Microsoft.Resources",
        "providerAuthorizationConsentState": null,
        "registrationPolicy": null,
        "registrationState": null,
        "resourceTypes": [
          {
            "aliases": null,
            "apiProfiles": null,
            "apiVersions": null,
            "capabilities": null,
            "defaultApiVersion": null,
            "locationMappings": null,
            "locations": [
              "eastus"
            ],
            "properties": null,
            "resourceType": "resourceGroups",
            "zoneMappings": null
          },
          {
            "aliases": null,
            "apiProfiles": null,
            "apiVersions": null,
            "capabilities": null,
            "defaultApiVersion": null,
            "locationMappings": null,
            "locations": [
              null
            ],
            "properties": null,
            "resourceType": "deployments",
            "zoneMappings": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "templateHash": "7124063297348834220",
    "templateLink": null,
    "timestamp": "2024-02-14T10:16:45.296532+00:00",
    "validatedResources": null
  },
  "tags": null,
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments"
}
```

**Issue**
Even after successful deployment, I am not able to see the above 2 resources in the Azure portal. Nor do I see any errors.
Please let me know the root cause behind. Any help/suggestion would help me a lot.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Can you please check that in Azure Portal you are at the right directory and not having any filters at the subscription? To be safe, go to Subscription, choose the one you have deployed the resources to and go to All Resources, if possible please check the "Deployment" option too and share additional details

Comment: It looks like this question was subject to significant edits after an answer was made. This may be confusing for future readers, who may wonder how the answer does not appear to relate to the question. I have thus rolled it back to the state it was in when the question was solved. If you want to record the code you used for your solution, then please add a self-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a very transient problem happens with bicep environment. Check below steps to resolve the issue.

***Need to check below:***

Firstly, check all the resource names with suffixes or prefixes are correctly aligned to the bicep name policy.

Go to the `Deployments` section under `resource group` blade and check the deployment history to check if any errors are occurred during deployment as shown below.

[image]

Make sure you have the proper `Contributor & Reader` permissions to access and view the resource after deployment.

Use [`az resource show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az-resource-show) CLI command to check the resource existence if the resource is not found in Portal.

I tried the same code as you, executed using `Visual Studio code` editor and was able to deploy, view the resources successfully as shown below.

**`main.bicep`**:

```bash
param prefix string = 'janu'
param environment string = 'dev'
param deploymentLocation string = 'eastUS'
param environmentType string = 'prod'

var storageAccountSkuName = (environmentType == 'prod') ? 'Standard_GRS' : 'Standard_LRS'
targetScope = 'subscription'
resource resourceGroup 'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2023-07-01' = {
   name: '${prefix}-${environment}-rg'
   location: deploymentLocation
}
 module storageAccount 'storage.bicep' = {
   scope: resourceGroup
   name: 'storageModule'
   params: {
     storageAccountName: '${prefix}${environment}sa'
     storageAccountLocation: deploymentLocation
     storageAccountSkuName: storageAccountSkuName
  }
}
```

**`storage.bicep`**:

```bash
param storageAccountName string = 'newjahs'
param storageAccountLocation string = resourceGroup().location
param storageAccountSkuName string = 'Standard_LRS'
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-01-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  location: storageAccountLocation
  sku: {
    name: storageAccountSkuName
  }
  kind: 'Storage'
}
```

[image]

[image]

*Reference:* [Troubleshooting MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/overview) & [Deployment issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/error-not-found?tabs=bicep)